# Link Replacement With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace directory links with javascript. for example i want to change http://mysite.com/cdn/backup/Pic.jpg in to http://mysite.com/newcdn/folder/Pic.jpg.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://mysite.com/cdn/backup/Pic.jpg" />
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/cdn/backup/Vid.flv"></iframe>

<script>
var str="cdn/backup/";
var n=str.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

So, this codes not working for me. please correct if there are any error in script. thanks in advance.

Comment: you are doing nothing with 'n'.

Comment: Are you trying to change the src of the image changing its folder?

Comment: your variable "str" is a local variable, you're going to have to get the img element by id/class/DOM/whatever...then change the src attribute.

Comment: The problem is to update the whole HTML code, you should move the script code to the head

Comment: yes, i want to change. but i want to place that code in head. when page will load by user, all links will change with my new folder source.

Comment: All the links? Are you talking about `<img>` AND `<a>` tags? Or only images?

Comment: this has to be done server side not client side. You will issue request to old cdn for each image tags and then a new one for the new cdn eventually changing the src attribute. This will result in poor loading performance for your users. Please edit your img src attribute in the source file or change this on the server side.

Comment: the question is WHY?????

Comment: Definitely has to be done server side. Why don't you just open the page in notepad and Find and replace.

Comment: @william i have 2000+ pages. so would you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to change the src of the `<img>` tag(which is what I'm supposing, reading the question) then you need to do something like this:

```
function changeSrc() {
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.src = img.src.replace('cdn/backup/', 'newcdn/folder/');
}

window.onload = changeSrc;
```

From the comments I read that you want to change ALL the `src`s, so the code will look like this:

```
function changeAllSrcs() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var img = imgs[i];
        img.src = img.src.replace('cdn/backup/', 'newcdn/folder/');
    }
}

window.onload = changeAllSrcs;
```

I don't know if this is a good way to do this, but if you want to replace all the occurences with link then you should do something like this(I don't like this solution, and it is not totally safe too, anyway it should do the job):

```
function replaceLinks() {
    var bodyHtml = document.body.innerHTML,
        replaced = bodyHtml.replace(/cdn\/backup/g, 'newcdn/folder/');
    document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
}
window.onload = replaceLinks;
```

Comment: i want to change everything. like CSS, JS, IMG, Video Links etc...

Answer (score 1):

access element and replace src attribute.

to change src of all img elements:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
length = img.length;

while(length--) {
    img[length].src = img[length].src.replace('cdn/backup/', 'newcdn/folder/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use JQuery you could do this:

```
$.each($("img"),function(key,value){
    value.src = value.src.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
});
```

Same can be done for the iFrame if indeed necessary:

```
    $.each($("iframe"),function(key,value){
   value.src = value.src.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
});
```

Most likely you will need to do this on document load. So

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($("img"),function(key,value){
        value.src = value.src.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
    });
//AND/OR
    $.each($("iframe"),function(key,value){
        value.src = value.src.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var n=str.replace(/cdn\/backup/ig,"newcdn/folder/");
```

Comment: Only if the OP wants to replace every occurrence. But with the example given, the code is fine.

Comment: yup! example is for JPG. but i want to change everything. Such as css, js, vids, pics, htmls

Answer (score 0):

This code does not do what you think it is doing. 
This snippet
    var n=str.replace("Microsoft","W3Schools"); 
replaces the words Microsoft with W3Schools in the string str. You want this replacement to happen in the link text. You need to get the link text and replace it. One idea is to get all the elements in the DOM and replace their src attributes.

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("*")
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
 // Do something with the element here
     str = elements[i].getAttribute("src")
     var newstr=str.replace("cdn/backup/","newcdn/folder/");
     elements[i].setAttribute("src",newstr)
```

}